# Map JSON request and response to POJO with different names

Tags: json, rest, data-mapping

I refactored  a rest micro service as there was a change in the data model. But we want to keep the  json payload (of the service which is based on the old data model) as the payload is being used by multiple other services.

please suggest me a good approach to map json objects with the POJO fields ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Data {
    String new;

    @JsonProperty("new")
    public String getNew() {
      return new;
    }

    @JsonProperty("old")
    public void setNew(String old) {
      this.new = old;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried use @JsonProperty? if you are using jackson.

Comment: No , i did read some posts about using json property annotation, will try that . Thankyou